# Unable to create file with VideoWriter using OpenCV 3.1 on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, video-capture

My goal is to create a basic proof of concept app where I open an existing MP4 video, process the frames, and write it back, primarily through `OpenCV`.

While I am able to open the video and process the frames, I have not been able to write it back successfully. What little literature I have found online has either not worked, or is unanswered.

The following is the first approach I tried for writing the file:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
std::string filename = path.UTF8String;
self.videoCapture = cv::VideoCapture(filename);
if(!self.videoCapture.isOpened()) std::cout << "Unable to open source" << std::endl;

int width = static_cast<int>(self.videoCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
int height = static_cast<int>(self.videoCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
double fps = self.videoCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
cv::VideoWriter videoWriter("output.mp4", self.videoCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC), fps, cv::Size(width, height));
if (!videoWriter.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open writer" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

One immediate issue with this approach is that the values I obtain for width, height, fps and pretty much anything else related to `CV_CAP` is always 1. I read about it being an issue with certain file types, but it occurs with mp4, mov and mkv, so that did not help.

Next, I hard coded values using what I knew to be true for the video, but was getting the same result with it unable to open the writer.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
std::string filename = path.UTF8String;
self.videoCapture = cv::VideoCapture(filename);
if(!self.videoCapture.isOpened()) std::cout << "Unable to open source" << std::endl;
cv::VideoWriter videoWriter("output.mkv", CV_FOURCC('m','p', '4', 'v'), 30, cv::Size(1920, 1080));

if (!videoWriter.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Output video could not be opened" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

For what it is worth, I did read about there being issues with the output file existing, so I deleted the file & changed the name, without any luck.

I also changed the FOURCC value to several other formats & updated the output name accordingly, again, without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with `cv::VideoWriter` because it couldn't save processed video too.

Finally I gave up this, now I'm using `AVAssetWriter` : (

I hope somebody solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int fourcc = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v');//mp4
double rate = 30; // frame rate
int capture_width = 480; 
int capture_height = 640;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *mp4_path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"];
writer.open([mp4_path UTF8String], 
            cv::CAP_AVFOUNDATION, 
            fourcc, 
            rate, 
            cv::Size(capture_width, capture_height),
            true);
```

work well for me.